# Python equivalent code of javax.crypto.Cipher

Tags: java, python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have java code to Encrypt the text using pem certificate as following

```
/* Load Public key from certificate file */
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("cert.pem");
Certificate cer = fact.generateCertificate(is);
PublicKey publicKey = cer.getPublicKey();

/* Encrypt data using public key */
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
String encryptedData = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

I am able to extract the public key from cert.pem using following steps in python:

```
# Extract public key from certificate file using openssl 
openssl x509 -inform pem -in cert.pem  -pubkey -noout > publickey.pem

# Load public key in python 
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
pubkey = open('publickey.pem').read()
key = RSA.importKey(pubkey)
```

The Java code results in different encrypted string for the a text for each new run where as if I use following python code to encrypt the data it produces same encrypted string for the a text for each new run.

```
b64encode(key.encrypt(data, 32)[0])
```

Now I am not sure how to encrypt the data in python that gives same result as above Java code. Can you suggest something, I have searched all over internet and haven't found any correct solution ?

Comment: The Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5 module is what is needed for interoperability with java. If you decide to go with the more modern OAEP padding then use Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`